# Site Guest User Record Creation

Tags: visualforce, force.com-sites, guest-user

i created a simple VF page that has input fields that lead to the creation of a record in a custom object created by me. i created a Site and set "Active Site Home Page" as this visual force page. if i am signed into the salesforce org i can submit records, but if i visit the site without being signed in i cannot create a record i get an error stating i must be signed in. i have allowed site guest user permissions in public access settings. as well as added site-guest user to be able to view the vf page.

i would like for anyone from the outside whom does not have a an account to be able to submit records into this custom object. 
Am i missing a step to allow the site-guest user to submit records into this object?

i saw below the response that shows edit public-access settings which i have already done.

Comment: If you are getting the authorization required error it is a permissions issue. Check FLS as well as access to the object. A single field with no access that is displayed not he VF page will cause this to happen

Answer (score 3):

Yes, your guest user can create, update, and delete records if they have the appropriate profile permissions. To view the profile permissions for the Site.com Guest User, go to Setup > Develop > Sites > Site Label > Public Access Settings > Object Settings, and adjust the objects and fields you want to enable access to. Note that you still need to write your own Visualforce pages (as you've done), and enable those pages on the Site. Once you've done all of that, it should work as you expect.

Comment: isn't there a restriction on CRUD upon standard objects or has that been lifted? (I realize OP was about custom objects)

Comment: @cropredy Site.com Guest users have fewer CRUD permissions than some other license types. In my org, I can see that they have CR on Accounts, Assets, Campaigns, Cases, Contacts, Contracts, Documents, Leads, Opportunities, Orders, Quotes, and Solutions, and R on Price Books, Products, Questions, and Ideas. Custom objects can have full CRUD.